# Movie circa 2005? Involves cops, gangsters, demons?

Tags: story-identification, movie, demons, crime

There's a movie I watched a few years ago. It's crap, but it's really bugging me that I can't think of its name.

I think it was released around 2005 (possibly earlier, but no earlier than 2003 or later than 2006).

I think it's set in Venice, or Santa Monica (or another beach town).

There's an undercover cop, and there's a gang. This gang turns out to be more, they're demons or something like that.

I watched this movie on DVD about 10 years ago, and I can't find a trace of it using multiple search strings. I think this needs someone who knows the movie. Any ideas anybody?

Comment: When you watched it on DVD, was a recent release? Do you know if it ever made it to theaters?

Comment: It was a recent release. I'm fairly confident it was straight to DVD.

Answer (score 2):

Is it "[Cast a Deadly Spell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101550/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_56)" from 1991?

> In 1948 Los Angeles, everyone uses magic- everyone except hard-boiled
> private detective H. Phillip Lovecraft, who refuses for "personal
> reasons." Lovecraft is hired by a mysterious rich man to recover a
> stolen book, the Necronomicon. Investigating, he finds that the book
> holds the key to taking over the world by magical means, releasing the
> "Old Ones".

Answer (score 0):

Is it **[Max Payne](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0467197/)**, released in 2008? It's a little later than you were thinking, but I immediately thought of it when you said

> "cops and demons."